# jQuery serializeObject strips out html from textarea when using IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, serialization, internet-explorer-9

I am using tinyMCE to create html formatted text and then posting it so it can be inserted into a database.

However, when I serialize the form, the html gets stripped out when using IE9. Here's the offending line in my code.

```
var data = $('form#myForm').serializeObject();
```

Does anyone know what it is in the serializeObject plugin that is stripping out the html code, and how to fix it??

Comment: You should be using `serialize()` instead of `serializeObject()`. The latter encodes the data to JSON.

Comment: @Jay Blanchard Using serialize also strips out the html tags from the textarea.